# How to neatly handle authentication when calling an API

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I am looking for some advice on how best to handle the authentication when calling an API from a web app.

I have inherited an blazor .net core project, that is fundamentally a UI for API calls, to display data to the user.

When the user logs on, the application makes a call to the `token` endpoint of the API, and if it is a success, it proceeds, and it stores the token in a class that the pages can access, and this token is then passed down the layers, so it can be included in the header for the API call.

I need to make some changes to this app, and I am not a fan of how this is currently handled. I would ideally like to have middleware, that adds the token to each call, so the code in the service layer is much cleaner, but, the problem I have is, I would either need to cache the token globally (is that secure?) or, the username and password, so I can get a token and add it to each call.

Does anyone have any advice for a project that is set up like this? I have never had to deal with users having different permissions based on the token, so have been able to keep creds in config, and pull them out in the middleware to get the token for each call.

Obviously security is paramount here, I don't really want to expose credentials or the token itself.

Comment: To make life even harder, if you don't have a MIME message you can use [MsgReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MsgReader) which can handle Outlook files as well. If `MsgReader.Outlook.Storage.Message` accepts a stream input, the solution is a single line, same as MimeKit. If you want a *specific* answer with code though, people need to know the actual format so they can use the correct library, write and *test* an answer

Comment: Message [does accept a stream](https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader/blob/master/MsgReaderCore/Outlook/Message.cs#L1486) which means you can parse your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented adding token to each api call through message handler (in Blazor WASM):

in Program.cs/Startup

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<YourHttpClient>().ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomMessageHandler>();
```

CustomMessageHandler

```
public class CustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private AuthenticationStateProvider provider;
    private readonly ILocalStoragee localStorage;
    private readonly NavigationManager navigation;

    public CustomMessageHandler(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider, 
         ILocalStorage localStorage,
         NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        provider = authenticationStateProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(authenticationStateProvider));
        localStorage = localStorage ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(localStorage));
        navigation = navigation ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(navigation));
    }

    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("token");
        
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        /// other headers       

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        /// handle common status codes
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)provider).MarkUserAsLoggedOut();
            navigation.NavigateTo("login");
            return default;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, at what point are you adding the token to the local storage? Do you use the creds the user logged in with to make a call to get a token, and add it at that point? Do you know if local storage is secure, and it is OK to store sensitive data? Cheers

Comment: User log in with login/pass, if it success then token is stored to any storage (in this case localstorage, you can even store it in some singleton, but it requires enter creds each time when app is started). Token has expiration time so even if it's compromised it invalidated after 24h.

Comment: @Leonidas199x also you can protect you token using for e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Solutaris.InfoWARE.ProtectedBrowserStorage

Comment: can I ask, are you using a Blazor server app?

Comment: Blazor WASM (webassembly) - client side